# Drawing a curved plot in tikz

Tags: tikz-pgf

I need some help in tikz. I don't know how to draw a curved plot like this red one on the picture, I have already prepared the axis, dashed line and these arrows.
[image]

There is my code:

```
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[
   axis lines = left,
   xmin=0, xmax=10,
   ymin=0, ymax=10,
    xtick = \empty, ytick = {0},
    clip = false,
]
    \node [below] at (current axis.right of origin) {$t$};
    \node [left] at (current axis.above origin) {$E$};

    \addplot[color = grey!60!white, dashed, thick] coordinates {(0,4) (8,4)};

    \draw[-{Triangle}, grey!80!white, opacity = 0.8] (1.5,0.1) to (1.5, 3.9);
    \draw[-{Triangle}, grey!80!white, opacity = 0.8] (7,0.1) to (7, 1.9);
    \draw[-{Triangle}, grey!80!white, opacity = 0.8] (4.5,4.1) to (4.5, 6.9);
    
    \node [right] at (1.5,2) {$E_s$};
    \node [right] at (7,1) {$E_p$};
    \node [right] at (4.5,5.5) {$E_a$};
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
```

Can someone help me, please?

Comment: Please, complete you snippet to a compilable document... see https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/6255/why-does-tex-require-such-elaborate-mwes

Comment: And please add a screenshot of the drawing your posted code produces.

Comment: Very similar to this: https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/625244/47927

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming the red curve is just representative and not a specific function, this is probably easier with just straightforward TikZ commands.

[image]

Use `\coordinate` to name specific points, then `\draw` to draw the axes, grid and red curve, as well as the arrows. Use `node`s to place labels on the arrows.

The only complicated part is the brace with `H`. You need the `decorations.pathreplacing` library for that.

If you want more control over the curve, you can read about Bézier curves in the [TikZ manual](https://ctan.mirrors.hoobly.com/graphics/pgf/base/doc/pgfmanual.pdf) (sections 2.4 or 14.3).

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows.meta, decorations.pathreplacing}
\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}[>=Straight Barb]
\draw[gray!30] (-.5,-.2) grid (8.8,6.7);
\draw[very thick, <->] (0,6.5)node[below left=2pt]{$E$} -- (0,0) -- (8.5,0);
\coordinate (A) at (0,2.5);
\coordinate (B) at (1.5,2.5); \coordinate (B0) at (1.5,0);
\coordinate (C) at (3.5, 4.5); \coordinate (C0) at (3.5, 2.5);
\coordinate (D) at (5.8,1.2); \coordinate (D0) at (5.8,0);
\draw[thick, red, looseness=.7] (A) -- (B) to[out=0, in=180] (C) to[out=0, in=180] (D) --++ (2,0);
\draw[dashed] (B) --++ (6.5,0);
\draw[thick, gray, <->] (B) --node[right]{$E_s$} (B0);
\draw[thick, gray, <->] (C) --node[right]{$E_a$} (C0);
\draw[thick, gray, <->] (D) --node[right]{$E_p$} (D0);
\draw[decorate, decoration=brace, thick] (8.1,2.5)--node[right]{$\Delta H$}(8.1,1.2);
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```