# Graphing Reaction Curve using PGFPlots

Tags: tikz-pgf

I want to graph a curve that looks like this

[image]

in my LaTex document and I have tried doing this by trying to find the equation of the function with this graph but I haven't been able to find this function. Is there any other way I can graph this?

Comment: Does [Easy curves in TikZ](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/33607/106162) help?

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! Something like [Energy diagram for an exothermic reaction in TikZ](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/625244/47927)?

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.